# Text on top of Image from SQL database

Tags: php, sql, dynamic, imaging, banner

So I am trying to figure out how to do this: http://www.hetemeel.com/einsteinform.php
with my own image. I also need to figure out how to replace the text-box with fetching text from an SQL database. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try playing around with this script.

```
$sql = "SELECT some_text FROM some_table LIMIT 1";
$rs = mysql_query($sql) or die();
$arr = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);

header ("Content-type: image/png");
$string = $arr['some_text'];
// try changing this as well
$font = 4;
$width = imagefontwidth($font) * strlen($string) ;
$height = imagefontheight($font) ;
$im = imagecreatefrompng("/path/to/someimagefile");
$x = imagesx($im) - $width ;
$y = imagesy($im) - $height;
$backgroundColor = imagecolorallocate ($im, 255, 255, 255);
$textColor = imagecolorallocate ($im, 0, 0,0);
imagestring ($im, $font, $x, $y,  $string, $textColor);
imagepng($im);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make this image a background-image for the div, for the text displayed in the image you can use CSS3 to transform the text to look like the way you saw using:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(15deg); /* rotate the text by 15 degree for chrome */
-moz-transform: rotate(15deg); /* for mozilla */
transform: rotate(15deg); /* for future, when css3 is standard and Opera */
```

and use a font to give it a feeling that it is hand written like "Buxton Sketch" font name.
then use padding-left property for this text to position it the way you want in the image.

i hope this will be useful.

Comment: +1 for such an interesting solution. Three drawbacks, 1) hard time saving the picture; 2) hard time for CSS3 unsupported browsers; 3) browsers apply anti-aliasing when transforms are used, and sometimes it turns out choppy.